# Background image linked to mesh?

Tags: mesh, image

I'm trying to add background images to my project. I added the first one fine, scaled and moved it where I wanted, but when I add the 2nd one for some reason it links to my mesh. If I rotate/scale/move either one, the other goes with it. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot and had proportional editing on. :)

Comment: Happens to everyone :).